# Flux + React: when to keep state of visual components at store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Sometimes it's not obvious: *where I should keep state of React view, i.e. active tab, selected option, toggler value, is input validated flag?*

Actually there are two options:

1. Throw an action and keep that data in store
2. Keep that data as view's state

*Which of them is better? Are stores intended only for data from server?*

---

My considerations:

1. That's bad to keep that data in store, because that lead to chain of actions. Example: you need to download data on tab selection - so you trigger an action `NEW_TAB_SELECTED` and from the store which handle it trigger a new action `DOWLOAD_TAB_DATA`.
2. Keeping data in view allow to avoid the first action (`NEW_TAB_SELECTED`) and avoid action chains. But how to keep selected tab if I want to leave this view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things that should be kept in the component's state are things which *only affect that component*.

So, for example, if you have a component which opens to reveal more content then the `isOpen` flag can be kept in state because it's internal to the component.

If the information is not part of the component (such as the text of a message and whether the message has been read) then it should be kept in a store and circulated through the app as needed.

Changing the state of a component will cause it to redraw, so try to keep state to the minimal possible representation of its state, and only store those properties in `this.state`.

Therefore, from what I can gather from your question, I'd suggest keeping active tab, selected option, toggler value and whether the input is validated in `this.state`. They are all properties of the component but don't affect any other components. I'd keep the data which populates the views in a store. I'd keep the flags which indicate the state of the view in `this.state`.

Hope that helps.